# How to save the width of a tabular and use it later?

Tags: tables, minipage, linewidth

I am trying to append a `minipage` to a `tabularx` or a `tabular`, inside a `table`, the minipage being of the same width as the `tabular(x)`.

I made a MWE to try some things, but that brought up a new question, albeit off topic: In the MWE below, why does the value of `\linewidth` depend on whether there is anything right before it (to the left of it)? Note how the value changes inside the `tabular` just by adding text before it or by setting it in `bf`, but not inside `multicolumn` and not outside `tabular`. Has that something to do with when the horizontal mode or a group begins? I have added `\textwidth` and `\columnwidth` only as a reference for me.

BTT: How can I let the width of a `minipage` *automatically* be the same as that of a`tabular(x)`? Of course, I can manually give a`minipage` the same width as a`tabularx`, but how can I save the width of a `tabular` and use it after `\end{tabular}` but before `\end{table}`? In that place, `\hsize` naturally has a completely different value than the width of the `tabular`, so my approach below is nonsense. As I have absolutely no clue as to how to go about this, I am leaving the MWE here. It shows where I want to place the `minipage` (in the place of `\note{…}`).

```
\documentclass[DIV=15]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\hsize}%
        \rule{1pt}{1.5ex} minipage of width \texttt{hsize}, inside table, but outside tabular\hfill\rule{1pt}{1.5ex}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\recalctypearea
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\centering%
\caption{\the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{110mm}lllll@{}}
    \toprule
    There is a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: a linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    a \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: \textbf{linewidth,} columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \textbf{\the\linewidth,} \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: textwidth, \textbf{linewidth,} columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\textwidth, \textbf{\the\linewidth,} \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: textwidth, linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{multicol. all columns: \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize}\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{multicol. all columns: --\the\textwidth--, --\the\linewidth--, --\the\columnwidth--, --\the\hsize--}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\medskip%
Outside tabular, inside table: \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize

\medskip%
Outside tabular, inside table: a \the\textwidth, b \the\linewidth, c \the\columnwidth, d \the\hsize

\medskip%
\note{a}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

Original MWE *(a lot of code):*

```
\documentclass[pagesize, DIV=15, parskip = half-]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcommand{\note}[1]{%
    \begin{minipage}{\hsize}%
        \textbf{#1}\quad\rule{1pt}{1ex}\hfill\rule{1pt}{1ex}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\newcommand{\notesonice}[2]{%
    \begin{minipage}{#1}%
        \textbf{#2}\quad\rule{1pt}{1ex}\hfill\rule{1pt}{1ex}%
    \end{minipage}%
}

\recalctypearea
\begin{document}
textwidth, linewidth, columnwidth, hsize:\\
\the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize

--textwidth--, --linewidth--, --columnwidth--, --hsize--:\\
--\the\textwidth--, --\the\linewidth--, --\the\columnwidth--, --\the\hsize--

\begin{table}[h]
\centering%
\caption{\the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize}
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|l|l|@{}}
    \hline
    \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize &&\\
    \hline
    A & B & C\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering%
\caption{\the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize, but without lines}
\begin{tabular}{@{}lll@{}}
    \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize &&\\
    A & B & C
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering%
\caption{\the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize}
\begin{tabularx}{0.95\linewidth}{@{}Xlllll@{}}
    \toprule
    There is a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a house & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: a linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    a \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: \textbf{linewidth,} columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \textbf{\the\linewidth,} \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: textwidth, \textbf{linewidth,} columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\textwidth, \textbf{\the\linewidth,} \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: textwidth, linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{multicolumn all six columns: \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize}\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{multicolumn all six columns: --\the\textwidth--, --\the\linewidth--, --\the\columnwidth--, --\the\hsize--}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

Outside tabular, inside table: \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize

Outside tabular, inside table: a \the\textwidth, b \the\linewidth, c \the\columnwidth, d \the\hsize

\note{a}

\notesonice{0.95\linewidth}{b}
\end{table}

478.00635\,pt:\\
\rule{478.00635pt}{1pt}

355.4792\,pt:\\
\hspace*{0.025\linewidth}\rule{355.4792pt}{1pt}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Did you consider using \textwidth correctly? https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Lengths , Examples e.g. via: https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Btextwidth%5D+minipage

Comment: you posted a lot of code but it isn't clear what you are demonstrating. Basically only `\hsize` is set up in an X column, you can set `\linewidth` to `\hsize` for nested list constructs

Comment: Why does the value of \linewidth depend on whether there is anything right before it (to the left of it)? Because is the width of the actual line, not the width of the *page* text  area (\textwidth) nor the width of the text columns in two columns *pages*. Although some times all they match, if you want  for instance, an image inside a item list (i.e., indented text) then you want to use `width=\linewidth`, not `width=\textwidth` nor `width=\columnwidth`.  A  `\rule{\linewidth}{10pt}` fit in a table with a `p{1cm}` column. Try now with `\rule{\textwidth}{10pt}`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I reduced the MWE and explained a bit more what I want to show. Do you mean, `\hsize` is set up in X columns, but not in columns of any other type? Do minipages inside tables count as nested list constructs?

Comment: no a minipage is not a list. As for your main question, it is two different ones, easiest is `How can I let the width of a minipage automatically be the same as that of the tabularx?`  As a `\begin{tabularx}{300pt}` is 300pt wide so a `\begin{minipage}{300pt}` is the same width, but is that really the question you meant to ask?

Comment: No, I just noticed, while working on my document. I changed the MWE, switched from `tabularx` to `tabular`. That is where I need such a construct more often.

Comment: I just realised how tired I must have been when I wrote my question. I have clarified it, hopefully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you're looking for `threeparttable`. Anyway, you can define a `measuredtabular` environment for the job:

```
\documentclass[DIV=15]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\newlength{\tabularwidth}
\newsavebox{\measuredtabularbox}
\newenvironment{measuredtabular}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\measuredtabularbox}\begin{tabular}}
 {\end{tabular}\end{lrbox}%
  \global\tabularwidth=\wd\measuredtabularbox
  \usebox{\measuredtabularbox}%
 }

\recalctypearea

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering

\caption{\the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize}

\begin{measuredtabular}{@{}p{110mm}lllll@{}}
    \toprule
    There is a house a house a house a house a house a house a house a 
    house a house a house a house a house a house & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: a linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    a \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: \textbf{linewidth,} columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \textbf{\the\linewidth,} \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: textwidth, \textbf{linewidth,} columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\textwidth, \textbf{\the\linewidth,} \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    Below: textwidth, linewidth, columnwidth, hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth, \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize & B & C & D & E & F\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{multicol. all columns: \the\textwidth, \the\linewidth,
    \the\columnwidth, \the\hsize}\\
    \midrule
    \multicolumn{6}{c}{multicol. all columns: --\the\textwidth--, --\the\linewidth--,
    --\the\columnwidth--, --\the\hsize--}\\
    \bottomrule
\end{measuredtabular}

\medskip

\begin{minipage}{\tabularwidth}
There is a house a house a house a house a house a house a house
a house a house a house a house a house a house
a house a house a house a house a house a house
a house a house a house a house a house a house
a house a house a house a house a house a house
a house a house a house a house a house a house
\end{minipage}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You need nothing of this sort for `tabular*` or `tabularx` where you have to explicitly set the width, so you know it.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the hint towards `threeparttable`. That package has a somewhat elaborate documentation. I would have to dive deeper into things to make tables look the way I want. Anyway, it seems `threeparttable` sets the width of the caption to the width of the table, too. I am not sure if I want that. Apart from that, I tried a different take, using `\multicolumn{}{}{}` just before `\end{table}`, but that too requires to know the width of the table, as `\hsize` is not set to it when used as argument for `multicolumn` (see my MWEs).